# What is the date format for this string?

Tags: date, groovy

I've got the following date as a string

```
2017-03-01T10:15:41-0800
```

that I'm trying to use with

```
new Date().parse('dd/mm/yyyy', dateString)
```

However, I can't figure out the format.

Comment: There is no such parse method in the Date class. And a Java String is surrounded by double quotes. So that code can't even compile. And the pattern is obviously not the one you're giving. Google for "how to parse a date in Java". Uou will have tons of relevant results.

Comment: @JBNizet I think this could be a case of misstagging, as that's valid groovy

Comment: @user304966 is this actually a groovy question?

Comment: Yes this is a valid groovy question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dateString` and date format dont match.
Groovy Style:

```
def dateString =  "2017-03-01T10:15:41-0800"
new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", dateString)
```

Result:

```
Wed Mar 01 21:15:41 EAT 2017
```

You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more information about the date format pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX");
      Date parsed = format.parse("2017-03-01T10:15:41-0800");
    } catch (ParseException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/GpYb/0)

Comment: This is a really awkward way of parsing dates in Groovy. Even in Java, Java 8 date classes are less crufty than this.

Comment: When I answered the question only had the tag java no Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

*Date* class contains its own, **static** *parse* method (*JB Nizet* was wrong in his comment to your question).

For details see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

So if you perform this parsing only once, use just this method.

On the other hand, if you plan to perform such a conversion **multiple** times,
it is more efficient to create a *SimpleDateFormat* instance (once)
and then use it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, and you're on Java 8, avoid `java.util.Date`, and parse it into one of the new `java.time` classes:

```
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def dateString =  "2017-03-01T10:15:41-0800"

def date = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString,
                                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"))
```

If you then want this time in another zone (ie: UTC), you can do:

```
def utcDate = date.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```